# How can I hide the Theme link in Site Settings for SharePoint 2010

Tags: theme, custom-action, settings

Can I create a customAction to hide the Theme link in Site Settings in SharePoint 2010 ? If so, what does the Element.xml look like ?  I've tried the following:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction
  GroupId = "Customization"
  HideActionId = "Theme"
  Id = "HideTheme"
  Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings">
  </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

Correction: The above Element.xml is correct.  I thought I had the feature automatically activate on deployment which was not the case.  Once I activated the feature, the 'Theme' link disapeared from Site Settings.

Bismarck